# bring back removed elements from list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

i've got this code (part of game i'm trying to make) that checks the elements of a list with elements of another list...basically, what it does is compare each index of each element, if the 2 index are equal it removes it from the list

here's that code:

```
checkctr = 0
x = 0
while checkctr < 4:
    if p1guesslist[x] == hidden[x]: 
        black += 1
        p1nonhidden.remove(hidden[x]) #p1nonhidden is a copy of hidden
        p1nonmatch.remove(hidden[x]) #p1nonmatch is a copy of p1guesslist
    x += 1
    checkctr += 1
for p1guess in p1nonmatch: #p1guess is a 4 digit user input
    if p1guess in p1nonhidden:
        white += 1
```

an example of how the code works in the output:

```
hidden = [1, 1, 2, 3] #elements of this is randomly generated
p1guesslist = [1, 3, 2, 4] #elements of this list is from p1guess
black = 2 #initial value is 0
white = 1 #initial value is 0
```

if the index of both list is equal, black gets +1 and gets removed from the list. the remaining elements is then checked if they are in the list of hidden, if they are -white gets +1

the problem is, the program is supposed to ask for user input until a certain amount of number is reached, so p1guesslist changes elements every input..what happens is this:

```
hidden = [1, 1, 2, 3]
p1guesslist = [1, 3, 2, 4] #first input
black = 2
white = 1

p1guesslist = [1, 1, 2, 3] #second input
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

i am aware that because of the list.remove() the ValueError occurs...

so i was thinking if there is a way to bring back the elements that was removed from hidden to after checking is done to avoid the error

*i put a mini version of the game in this online notepad just incase you want to see it http://shrib.com/UMYKxGiY i used Python 3.4.1 to make that

Comment: make a copy of the list

Comment: wouldn't that mean there would be tons of list? and how do i replace a list? (sorry, i'm new to programming -python's my first to be honest)

Comment: why are you removing them if you want to keep them?

Comment: i don't want to keep them, i want to bring them back...if i don't remove them, and an index of first list is equal to the second list, it would add +1 on black and +1 on white (which is not supposed to happen, its either +1 black or +1 white or none at all)

Answer (score -1):

Handle the exception:

```
try:
    list.remove(x)
except ValueError:
    pass
```

. No more "x not in list."

Comment: awesome, this just made the problem smaller (i think). unfortunately if an element is removed, if i try to input a number equal to the element there will be no +1 on white..for example hidden = [1,2,3,4] first input = [1,5,5,5] score = [1, 0]; second input = [5,5,5,1] score = [0,0] (the second score should be [0, 1])

Comment: I strongly disagree. Rules of thumb are made for exceptions (ha), and this is precisely one. I had interpreted the OP's question to mean, "I'm looking for a way to remove the first instance of an item in a list if it is present." A ValueError occurs if and only if an item is not present in the list. There was clearly more to the OP's question, and I didn't think I could follow up adequately. Now take back your downvote!